# Cannot run Android app on real device, but works in emulator

Tags: android, xamarin.android

I've created a simple android project with Mono for Android Visual Studio 2010 that displays welcome string on the screen. Can run on emulator but failed in real device. Can you help me?

**Activity class**

```
using System;    
using Android.App; 
using Android.Content; 
using Android.Runtime; 
using Android.Views; 
using Android.Widget; 
using Android.OS;

namespace Welcome 
{
    [Activity(Label = "Welcome", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/icon")]
    public class Activity1 : Activity
    {
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate(bundle);

            TextView txt = new TextView(this);
            txt.Text = "Welcome, Android";
            SetContentView(txt);
        }
    } 
}
```

**Manifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:installLocation="preferExternal" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1">
      <uses-sdk android:targetSdkVersion="10" />
      <application android:label="WelcomeAndroid">
      </application>
    </manifest>
```

**Here is the log:**

```
Packaging application..
Microsoft (R) Build Engine Version 4.0.30319.1
[Microsoft .NET Framework, Version 4.0.30319.1]
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation 2007. All rights reserved.

Build started 6/8/2014 11:09:04 PM.
Project "C:\Users\yo\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Welcome\Welcome\Welcome.csproj" on node 1 (SignAndroidPackage target(s)).
_GenerateAndroidAssetsDir:
Skipping target "_GenerateAndroidAssetsDir" because it has no outputs.
_GenerateAndroidResourceDir:
  Copying file from "Resources\Layout\Main.axml" to "C:\Users\yo\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Welcome\Welcome\obj\Release\res\layout\main.xml".
_ResolveMonoAndroidSdks:
  MonoAndroid Tools: C:\Program Files\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\
  MonoAndroid Framework: C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v2.3\;C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\
  MonoAndroid Binaries: C:\Program Files\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\
  Android SDK: D:\My Downloads\Android Development\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20140321\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20140321\sdk\
  Java SDK: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_45\
_ValidateAndroidPackageProperties:
  GetAndroidPackageName Task
    ManifestFile: C:\Users\yo\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Welcome\Welcome\Properties\AndroidManifest.xml
    AssemblyName: Welcome
    PackageName: Welcome.Welcome
_ExtractLibraryProjectImports:
    Assemblies: 
      C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v2.3\Mono.Android.dll
      C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\mscorlib.dll
      C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\System.Core.dll
      C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\System.dll
      C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\System.Xml.dll
      C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\System.Xml.Linq.dll
    Jars: 
    ResolvedResourceDirectories: 
_CheckDuplicateJavaLibraries:
    JavaSourceFiles:
    JavaLibraries:
_UpdateAndroidResgen:
Skipping target "_UpdateAndroidResgen" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
GenerateTargetFrameworkMonikerAttribute:
Skipping target "GenerateTargetFrameworkMonikerAttribute" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
CoreCompile:
Skipping target "CoreCompile" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
CopyFilesToOutputDirectory:
  Welcome -> C:\Users\yo\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Welcome\Welcome\bin\Release\Welcome.dll
_ResolveAssemblies:
  ResolveAssemblies Task
    ReferenceAssembliesDirectory: C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v2.3\;C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\;;
    I18nAssemblies: 
    LinkMode: SdkOnly
    Assemblies:
      bin\Release\Welcome.dll
      C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v2.3\Mono.Android.dll
      C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\mscorlib.dll
      C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\System.Core.dll
      C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\System.dll
      C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\System.Xml.dll
      C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\System.Xml.Linq.dll
    [Output] ResolvedAssemblies:
      C:\Users\yo\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Welcome\Welcome\bin\Release\Welcome.dll
      C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\mscorlib.dll
      C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v2.3\Mono.Android.dll
      C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\System.Core.dll
      C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\System.dll
      C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Mono.Security.dll
      C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\System.Xml.dll
    [Output] ResolvedUserAssemblies:
      C:\Users\yo\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Welcome\Welcome\bin\Release\Welcome.dll
    [Output] ResolvedFrameworkAssemblies:
      C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\mscorlib.dll
      C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v2.3\Mono.Android.dll
      C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\System.Core.dll
      C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\System.dll
      C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Mono.Security.dll
      C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\System.Xml.dll
_StripEmbeddedLibraries:
    Assemblies: 
      obj\Release\assemblies\Welcome.dll
      obj\Release\assemblies\mscorlib.dll
      obj\Release\assemblies\Mono.Android.dll
      obj\Release\assemblies\System.Core.dll
      obj\Release\assemblies\System.dll
      obj\Release\assemblies\Mono.Security.dll
      obj\Release\assemblies\System.Xml.dll
_ResetLinkingFlag:
Building target "_ResetLinkingFlag" partially, because some output files are out of date with respect to their input files.
  Deleting file "obj\Release\link.flag".
_LinkAssemblies:
  LinkAssemblies Task
    UseSharedRuntime: False
    MainAssembly: obj\Release\assemblies\Welcome.dll
    OutputDirectory: obj\Release\android\assets\
    I18nAssemblies: 
    LinkMode: SdkOnly
    LinkDescriptions:
    ResolvedAssemblies:
      obj\Release\assemblies\Welcome.dll
      obj\Release\assemblies\mscorlib.dll
      obj\Release\assemblies\Mono.Android.dll
      obj\Release\assemblies\System.Core.dll
      obj\Release\assemblies\System.dll
      obj\Release\assemblies\Mono.Security.dll
      obj\Release\assemblies\System.Xml.dll
  Creating "obj\Release\link.flag" because "AlwaysCreate" was specified.
_PrepareAssemblies:
    Files
      obj\Release\android\assets\Welcome.dll
      obj\Release\android\assets\mscorlib.dll
      obj\Release\android\assets\Mono.Android.dll
      obj\Release\android\assets\System.Core.dll
      obj\Release\android\assets\System.dll
      obj\Release\android\assets\Mono.Security.dll
      obj\Release\android\assets\System.Xml.dll
    [Output] FilesThatExist
      obj\Release\android\assets\Welcome.dll
      obj\Release\android\assets\mscorlib.dll
      obj\Release\android\assets\Mono.Android.dll
      obj\Release\android\assets\System.Core.dll
      obj\Release\android\assets\System.dll
      obj\Release\android\assets\Mono.Security.dll
    Files
      obj\Release\android\assets\mscorlib.dll.mdb
      obj\Release\android\assets\Mono.Android.dll.mdb
      obj\Release\android\assets\System.Core.dll.mdb
      obj\Release\android\assets\System.dll.mdb
      obj\Release\android\assets\Mono.Security.dll.mdb
      obj\Release\android\assets\System.Xml.dll.mdb
    [Output] FilesThatExist
    Files
      obj\Release\android\assets\Welcome.dll
    [Output] FilesThatExist
      obj\Release\android\assets\Welcome.dll
    Files
      obj\Release\android\assets\mscorlib.dll
      obj\Release\android\assets\Mono.Android.dll
      obj\Release\android\assets\System.Core.dll
      obj\Release\android\assets\System.dll
      obj\Release\android\assets\Mono.Security.dll
      obj\Release\android\assets\System.Xml.dll
    [Output] FilesThatExist
      obj\Release\android\assets\mscorlib.dll
      obj\Release\android\assets\Mono.Android.dll
      obj\Release\android\assets\System.Core.dll
      obj\Release\android\assets\System.dll
      obj\Release\android\assets\Mono.Security.dll
_GenerateJavaStubs:
    ResolvedAssemblies:
      obj\Release\android\assets\Welcome.dll
      obj\Release\android\assets\mscorlib.dll
      obj\Release\android\assets\Mono.Android.dll
      obj\Release\android\assets\System.Core.dll
      obj\Release\android\assets\System.dll
      obj\Release\android\assets\Mono.Security.dll
    ResolvedUserAssemblies:
      obj\Release\android\assets\Welcome.dll
_AddStaticResources:
  Resource obj\Release\android\assets\machine.config is unchanged. Skipping.
  Resource obj\Release\android\src\mono\MonoRuntimeProvider.java is unchanged. Skipping.
_GeneratePackageManagerJava:
    ResolvedAssemblies:
      obj\Release\android\assets\Welcome.dll
      obj\Release\android\assets\mscorlib.dll
      obj\Release\android\assets\Mono.Android.dll
      obj\Release\android\assets\System.Core.dll
      obj\Release\android\assets\System.dll
      obj\Release\android\assets\Mono.Security.dll
    ResolvedUserAssemblies:
      obj\Release\android\assets\Welcome.dll
_CreateBaseApk:
    AdditionalResourceDirectories: 
  D:\My Downloads\Android Development\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20140321\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20140321\sdk\platform-tools\aapt.exe package -f -m -M obj\Release\android\AndroidManifest.xml -J C:\Users\yo\AppData\Local\Temp\nu1dup5n.g3c --custom-package welcome.welcome -F obj\Release\android\bin\packaged_resources.bk -S obj\Release\res -I "D:\My Downloads\Android Development\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20140321\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20140321\sdk\platforms\android-10\android.jar" --auto-add-overlay --debug-mode 
    RemovedDirectories: 
      C:\Users\yo\AppData\Local\Temp\nu1dup5n.g3c
_CompileJava:
Skipping target "_CompileJava" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
_CompileDex:
Skipping target "_CompileDex" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
_RemoveRegisterAttribute:
  Copying file from "obj\Release\android\assets\mscorlib.dll" to "obj\Release\android\assets\shrunk\mscorlib.dll".
  Copying file from "obj\Release\android\assets\Mono.Android.dll" to "obj\Release\android\assets\shrunk\Mono.Android.dll".
  Copying file from "obj\Release\android\assets\System.Core.dll" to "obj\Release\android\assets\shrunk\System.Core.dll".
  Copying file from "obj\Release\android\assets\System.dll" to "obj\Release\android\assets\shrunk\System.dll".
  Copying file from "obj\Release\android\assets\Mono.Security.dll" to "obj\Release\android\assets\shrunk\Mono.Security.dll".
  RemoveRegisterAttribute Task
    ShrunkFrameworkAssemblies:
      obj\Release\android\assets\shrunk\mscorlib.dll
      obj\Release\android\assets\shrunk\Mono.Android.dll
      obj\Release\android\assets\shrunk\System.Core.dll
      obj\Release\android\assets\shrunk\System.dll
      obj\Release\android\assets\shrunk\Mono.Security.dll
  Touching "obj\Release\android\assets\shrunk\shrunk.flag".
_BuildApkEmbed:
    ResolvedUserAssemblies:
      obj\Release\android\assets\Welcome.dll
    ResolvedFrameworkAssemblies:
      obj\Release\android\assets\shrunk\mscorlib.dll
      obj\Release\android\assets\shrunk\Mono.Android.dll
      obj\Release\android\assets\shrunk\System.Core.dll
      obj\Release\android\assets\shrunk\System.dll
      obj\Release\android\assets\shrunk\Mono.Security.dll
    NativeLibraries:
    JavaSourceFiles:
    JavaLibraries:
_Mandroid:
  Deleting file "obj\Release\android\bin\Welcome.Welcome.apk".
  Deleting file "bin\Release\Welcome.Welcome.apk".
  Mandroid Task
    Assemblies: bin\Release\Welcome.dll; C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v2.3\Mono.Android.dll; C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\mscorlib.dll; C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\System.Core.dll; C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\System.dll; C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\System.Xml.dll; C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\System.Xml.Linq.dll
    I18nAssemblies: 
    BuildDirectory: obj\Release\
    ReferenceAssembliesDirectory: C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v2.3\;C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\;;
    AndroidSdkDirectory: D:\My Downloads\Android Development\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20140321\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20140321\sdk\
    JavaSdkDirectory: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_45\
    AssetDirectory: obj\Release\assets\
    AndroidSdkPlatform: 10
    MonoAndroidToolsDirectory: C:\Program Files\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\
    ResourceDirectory: obj\Release\res\
    ManifestTemplate: C:\Users\yo\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Welcome\Welcome\Properties\AndroidManifest.xml
    Package: Welcome.Welcome
    NativeLibrary: 
    JavaSource: 
    Debug: False
    UseSharedRuntime: False
    SupportedAbis: armeabi;armeabi-v7a;x86
    LinkMode: SdkOnly
    ExtraArgs:  
  C:\Program Files\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\mandroid.exe -v --nosign --sdk-dir="D:\My Downloads\Android Development\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20140321\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20140321\sdk" --builddir="obj\Release\android" --framework-dir="C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v2.3" --framework-dir="C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0" -S="obj\Release\res" --package="Welcome.Welcome" --input="obj\Release\android\bin\resources_and_assemblies" --output="obj\Release\android\bin\Welcome.Welcome.apk"   --linksdkonly --noshared --abi="armeabi;armeabi-v7a;x86" --java-sdk-dir="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_45" --manifest-template="C:\Users\yo\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Welcome\Welcome\Properties\AndroidManifest.xml" --sdk-platform="10" "bin\Release\Welcome.dll" "C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v2.3\Mono.Android.dll" "C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\mscorlib.dll" "C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\System.Core.dll" "C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\System.dll" "C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\System.Xml.dll" "C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\System.Xml.Linq.dll" 
  Copying file from "obj\Release\android\bin\Welcome.Welcome.apk" to "bin\Release\Welcome.Welcome.apk".
  Deleting file "obj\Release\uploadflags.txt".
_Sign:
  C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_45\bin\jarsigner.exe -keystore "C:\Users\yo\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Mono for Android\debug.keystore" -storepass android -keypass android -digestalg SHA1 -sigalg md5withRSA -signedjar bin\Release\Welcome.Welcome-Signed-Unaligned.apk obj\Release\android\bin\Welcome.Welcome.apk androiddebugkey 
  Signed android package 'bin\Release\Welcome.Welcome-Signed.apk'
  Deleting file "bin\Release\Welcome.Welcome-Signed.apk".
  AndroidZipAlign Task
    AndroidSdkDirectory: D:\My Downloads\Android Development\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20140321\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20140321\sdk\
    Alignment: 4
    Source: bin\Release\Welcome.Welcome-Signed-Unaligned.apk
    Destination: bin\Release\Welcome.Welcome-Signed.apk
  D:\My Downloads\Android Development\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20140321\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20140321\sdk\tools\zipalign.exe 4 "bin\Release\Welcome.Welcome-Signed-Unaligned.apk" "bin\Release\Welcome.Welcome-Signed.apk" 
  Aligned android package 'bin\Release\Welcome.Welcome-Signed.apk'
  Deleting file "bin\Release\Welcome.Welcome-Signed-Unaligned.apk".
Done Building Project "C:\Users\yo\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Welcome\Welcome\Welcome.csproj" (SignAndroidPackage target(s)).

Build succeeded.
    0 Warning(s)
    0 Error(s)

Time Elapsed 00:00:12.27



Waiting for device..
Detecting installed packages
Detecting installed packages...

Removing previous version of application
Removing previous version of application...

Installing application on device
Copying application to device...
```

**After this, it prints the following:**

```
In mgmain JNI_OnLoad
The program 'Mono' has exited with code 255 (0xff).
```

Comment: @David..Please uncheck the Fast Deployment from project properties, and try if it runs. I am not sure it works, but you can try it

Comment: OK. I am trying. Let me see the result.

Comment: It is by default, disabled in release mode.

Comment: @SamusArin stop telling him nonsense. You can deploy to device and to app stores with the free version of Xamarin. Licensing is obviously not his problem. Have you tried deploying it in debug mode, with Fast Deployment disabled?

Comment: @SamusArin https://store.xamarin.com/ <-- See the first column? This applies to Xamarin Studio. If he is using Visual Studio he is either using the Trial version or something with at least a Business version, which both also perfectly fine deploy to devices.

Comment: @Cheesebaron My apologies for being a jerk CB, I got a rotten temper :(